How can I check when there are only opening or closing quotes in PHP to make replacements?
In a text that comes with a separator, I need to create several paragraphs for a document written in LaTeX. The purpose of this code is to replace any content within quotes with \textquote{the text}
Let's assume the following text:
$str="Irán pueblos numerosos diciendo: «Vamos a subir al monte del Señor, al templo del Dios de Jacob».|Él nos enseñará sus caminos y caminaremos por sus sendas.|Viene el Mesías, el Cristo; cuando venga, nos hará saber todas las cosas.";

I need to create the following content:
\fourargs
{Irán pueblos numerosos diciendo: \textquote{Vamos a subir al monte del Señor, al templo del Dios de Jacob}.}
{%
Él nos enseñará sus caminos y caminaremos por sus sendas.%
}{%
Viene el Mesías, el Cristo; cuando venga, nos hará saber todas las cosas.%
}{%
Él nos enseñará sus caminos y caminaremos por sus sendas.%
}
    

I can achieve this with the following code without any problem:
DEMO
$str="Irán pueblos numerosos diciendo: «Vamos a subir al monte del Señor, al templo del Dios de Jacob».|Él nos enseñará sus caminos y caminaremos por sus sendas.|Viene el Mesías, el Cristo; cuando venga, nos hará saber todas las cosas.";    
$html="";
$break=PHP_EOL."\t";
$quotes=["/'(.*?)'/",'/"(.*?)"/',"/«(.*?)»/","/“(.*?)”/"];
$textquote="\\textquote{\$1}";                  
$fourArgs="
\\fourargs
    {%s}
    {%%
        %s%%
    }{%%
        %s%%
    }{%%
        %s%%
    }";
$tmp=explode('|',preg_replace($quotes,$textquote,$str));
$html.=sprintf($fourArgs,
           $tmp[0],
           $tmp[1],
           $tmp[2],
           $tmp[1]
       );
echo $html;

My problem arises when the opening and closing quotes are placed in different groups when doing the explode. In that case, the replacement with textquote{...} does not work as expected.
Suppose the following code:
DEMO
The content of $str is as follows:
$str="Irán pueblos numerosos diciendo: «Vamos a subir al monte del Señor, al templo del Dios de Jacob.|Él nos enseñará sus caminos y caminaremos por sus sendas».|Viene el Mesías, el Cristo; cuando venga, nos hará saber todas las cosas.";    

The final result is as follows:
\fourargs
    {Irán pueblos numerosos diciendo: \textquote{Vamos a subir al monte del Señor, al templo del Dios de Jacob.}
    {%
        Él nos enseñará sus caminos y caminaremos por sus sendas}.%
    }{%
        Viene el Mesías, el Cristo; cuando venga, nos hará saber todas las cosas.%
    }{%
        Él nos enseñará sus caminos y caminaremos por sus sendas}.%
    }

But the expected result is:
\fourargs
    {Irán pueblos numerosos diciendo: \textquote{Vamos a subir al monte del Señor, al templo del Dios de Jacob}.}
    {%
        \textquote{Él nos enseñará sus caminos y caminaremos por sus sendas}.%
    }{%
        Viene el Mesías, el Cristo; cuando venga, nos hará saber todas las cosas.%
    }{%
        \textquote{Él nos enseñará sus caminos y caminaremos por sus sendas}.%
    }

How could I achieve the expected result in all cases?

Preprocess your string before your replacement like that:
$str = 'Irán … diciendo: «Vamos … Jacob.|Él nos … sendas».|Viene el … cosas.';

$pattern = <<<'REGEX'
~
(?<open> ' ) .*? (?<close> ' ) |
(?<open> " ) .*? (?<close> " ) |
(?<open> « ) .*? (?<close> » ) |
(?<open> “ ) .*? (?<close> ” )
~Jux
REGEX;

$replacement = fn($m) => str_replace('|', "{$m['close']}|{$m['open']}", $m[0]);

echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, $replacement, $str);

// Irán … diciendo: «Vamos … Jacob.»|«Él nos … sendas».|Viene el … cosas.


Pattern variant that uses the first character discrimination and a branch reset group:
$pattern = <<<'REGEX'
~
(?=['"«“])
(?|  (?<open> ' ) .*? (?<close> ' )
  |  ( " ) .*? ( " )
  |  ( « ) .*? ( » )
  |  ( “ ) .*? ( ” )
)
~ux
REGEX;

Pro: the pattern fails quickly on useless positions (positions without a quote) without to test each branch.
Note that in a branch reset group, you only have to define the names of capture groups in the first branch to set them automatically in other branches.

About your formatted string, you can also write it like that:
$fourArgs = '
\\fourargs
    {%s}
    {%%
        %s%%
    }{%%
        %s%%
    }{%%
        %2$s%%
    }';

// ...

$html .= vsprintf($fourArgs, $tmp);


Based on the example you provided, I have a simple solution. I assume that the | symbol is preceded by . here.
You can replace .| with }.|\textquote{ in the matching text to insert an additional \textquote block.
function textquotereplace(array $matches){
    $str = str_replace('.|', '}.|\\textquote{', $matches[1]);
    return "\\textquote{{$str}}";
}

$tmp=explode('|',preg_replace_callback($quotes,'textquotereplace',$str));


Thanks for your reply. The content of $str comes from a database, and the | symbol will not necessarily be preceded by ., but may be preceded by other punctuation marks or any other character. For example: San Lorenzo exclamó: «Yo adoro a mi Dios y sólo a él le sirvo;|por eso no temo tus tormentos.»|El Señor es mi roca en que me amparo."

"or any other character" So how do you decide whether to put the this character inside or outside }?

This case completely breaks the logic of the \fourargs command. I may need to change that logic at the LaTeX level. This is the relative question. For this case the output should be: R. San Lorenzo exclamó: «Yo adoro a mi Dios y sólo a él le sirvo; * por eso no temo tus tormentos.» V. El Señor es mi roca en que me amparo. R. Por eso no temo tus tormentos.
